# Will Migrating Content Between Sites Preserve CKEditor Styles?

Tags: wysiwyg

I have been entering content on my dev site using CKEditor, but now I'm worried that moving to the live site will erase all the styling I have done to these articles. Maybe that is a dumb question, because I have not found anything addressing this topic online. If I have the CKEditor module installed on the live site, when I transfer my content there, will all their fonts/colors/styling/etc be preserved? Thanks in advance

Comment: Related note: In the future, should I only add content to the live site instead of the dev site? I know this can be interpreted as an open-ended or subjective question since people might have different opinions, but I think this is an important question for new drupal site managers like me. Thanks

Comment: HI, Kristina. Each post is supposed to be limited to one question. You can ask the question in a separate post, but I would recommend framing it as a technical question in the context of your particular set-up (provide details!). Cheers -

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, as long as you keep your database integrity when migrating.**

CKEditor basically adds HTML tags and attributes to your data, which are saved in your fields' tables in the database. So, for example, if you have a *body* field that contains  text formatted like "Hello, **body**", and take a look at your field_data_body table, you will see something like this:

```
<p>Hello, <strong>body</strong>...
```